# How to store the output of for loop into a variable in RStudio

Tags: r, for-loop

Here is what I have done, I want to store all the values into a variable and will put some conditional statements on them later on. But in order to do so I believe that at least I should be able to store them into a variable. Can somebody explain how? Also I tried print() but then don't know how to store. Perhaps I should not do print()

```
A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- c(4,5,6)

for(i in seq_along(A)){
for(j in seq_along(B)){
    print(A[[i]]*B[[j]])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add other conditional statements later and want to continue with `for` loop you can modify your code as :

```
A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- c(4,5,6)
result <- numeric(length(A) * length(B))
z <- 0

for(i in seq_along(A)){
  for(j in seq_along(B)){
    z <- z + 1
    result[z] <- A[i] * B[j]
  }
}
```

---

You can also achieve the same output with `outer` :

```
result <- c(t(outer(A, B)))
```